# Incorrect Syntax near ')' When running a union query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to run this Union query and keep getting a Incorrect syntax near ')' error.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_ID, count(*)
AS TOTAL_TRANSACTIONS
FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION
WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE_ID = '9'
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) < '4'
UNION
SELECT TRANSACTION_STATUS_DATE
AS TRANS_DATE
FROM ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION
GROUP BY TRANSACTION_STATUS_DATE
HAVING (MONTH(TRANSACTION_STATUS_DATE) = MONTH(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate()))
AND YEAR(TRANSACTION_STATUS_DATE) = YEAR(dateadd(dd, -1, GetDate())
```

Comment: UNION is applicable on 2 queries containing the same number of columns and same corresponding column data types. So your UNION fails both.

Answer (score 1):

Count your brackets. The `(` after `HAVING` doesn't have a matching `)`.

Also, not appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 1):

There are 11 occurrences of an opening parenthesis while only 9 of a closing one. Hence, you are missing two closing parenthesis at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your query.

1) you cant union two query selecting different output

2)Missing ')'

For #1, it depends what you wanted to achieve

for #2, use online formatting tool to auto indenting and it will be easier to debug your syntax.